# Search Images Using Default search Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there any way by which i can search for image titles also in a page ??? by default it will search only for Content but is there any way to modify it so that it can search for image title s also ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Drupal Development and Hooks, you can use the drupal hook_search to add a functionality to search titles of images, as the hook takes an array with multiple values to search on , so in the end it will be your own code that will do the trick.